# How to activate algo.asNode() function is neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using neo4j 3.5.1 with apoc-3.5.0.1-all.jar and graph-algorithms-algo-3.5.0.1.jar. My config file has the following lines:

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*,algo.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*,algo.*
```

I can use the louvain community detection in cypher with the following command, but it fail when changing nodeId to algo.asNode(nodeId) in the RETURN statement. Is there a specific setup to use algo.asNode() function?

```
CALL algo.louvain.stream('User', 'FRIEND', {})
YIELD nodeId, community
// RETURN algo.asNode(nodeId).id AS user, community
RETURN nodeId AS user, community
ORDER BY community;
```

Comment: Older versions don't have this function yet. Upgrade to a newer one and it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, works well. Sorry, I can't mark the question as answered.

Comment: my current version is 1.1.9 and it doesn't support algo keyword anymore